# disable subpixel aliasing on html/css borders

Tags: html, css, subpixel

I'm using css `transform:scale` to scale some elements up, and now the borders, which were originally `1px solid black`, get some subpixel rendering - 'antialiasing' - since they are now `1.4px` or something. Exactly how it looks depends on the browser, but its blurry on all modern browsers.

Can I disable subpixel rendering for certain elements?

Comment: browser-specific solutions - eg css with vendor prefixes - are welcome too

Comment: ...if you use a CSS rule to transform/scale your elements, why don't you just adjust the borders in this same rule???

Comment: I should have mentioned the scale was dynamic - done with javascript. I didnt try to adjust the border-width with the same javascript, eg border-width:0.71px or something - might have been a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into a similar issue with downscaling using `transform: scale(ratio)`, except the borders would entirely dissapear on subpixel rendering instead of blurring.

Since I was in a similar use case (dynamic scaling with js), I decided to implement the javascript solution suggested in the comments by the original author:

```
container.style.transform = "scale(" + ratio + ")";
elementWithBorder.style.border = Math.ceil(1 / ratio) + "px solid lightgray";
```

In an upscaling situation I would however suggest Math.floor() to avoid 'fattening' the borders too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can control text antialiasing on WebKit with this css:
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
And sometimes forcing 3d acceleration with something like:
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
helps aliasing as well ( at least when using rotate in my experience).

Comment: Thanks, and correct, but I was asking for aliasing effects on non-text elements - specifically borders. these arent affected by `-webkit-font-smoothing` and the translateZ trick had no effect...

Answer (score 0):

It's blurry because standard displays of 72 dpi can't render fractional pixel sizes, as I'm sure you understand. In addition, there is [nothing within the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions) to affect rendering or aliasing of borders.

A pixel width of 2 may give you better results, yet just about everything will blur.

Some retina devices and displays do support [sub-pixel border widths](http://dieulot.net/css-retina-hairline) but there are no consistent solutions when it comes to cross-browser support.

In my own testing, I found better results when scaling from a corner, as opposed to center by default. As well as stepping up in quarter or half amounts.

```
transform: scale(1.25);
transform-origin: left top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `perspective` property seems to do the trick:

```
.subpixel-modal {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    perspective: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: I also don't know why this works, but `transform: perspective(0);` and `perspective: 0;` seem to work as well.